# Sending Binary data via Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, webkit

I want to send a binary post data with jquery ajax to the server backend but i can not success with it.

The success post data like this

[image: Success Result]

[image: Success result source]

I am using code like this

```
    var newBoundary = createRandom(16)
var datax  = '------WebKitFormBoundary'+ newBoundary +'\n'
    datax += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="queryOptionsDTO"; filename="blob"\n'
    datax += 'Content-Type: application/json\n\n'

    datax += '{"queryPage":{"initialPage":0,"pageSize":15},"sortInfo":{"sortFields":[{"propertyName":"updateDate","ascending":false}]},"queryParameterDTOs":[{"queryParameterType":"SIMILARITY","propertyName":"kurum.gorunenAd","similarityStrategy":"START"},{"queryParameterType":"SIMILARITY","propertyName":"markaAdi","similarityStrategy":"START"},{"queryParameterType":"EQUALITY","propertyName":"barkodNumarasi","value":"'+ barkod +'"},{"queryParameterType":"SIMILARITY","propertyName":"piyasayaArzIsmi","similarityStrategy":"START"},{"queryParameterType":"SIMILARITY","propertyName":"urunCinsi","similarityStrategy":"START"},{"queryParameterType":"CONTEXT","propertyName":"menseiUlkeAdi","similarityStrategy":"START"},{"queryParameterType":"EQUALITY","propertyName":"ucYasAltiCocuklarIcinUretilmis"},{"queryParameterType":"EQUALITY","propertyName":"ithalImalBilgisi"}],"queryTotal":false}\n'

    $.ajax({
     beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("anonymousUtsToken",sessionStorage.getItem("anonymousUtsToken"));
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("preferredLocale","tr-TR");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json, text/plain, */*");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary"+ newBoundary);
    },
        url: '/UTS/vat/rest/vatKozmetik/kozmetikUrunSorgula',
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"binary",
        data: datax,
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        success:function (data, status, req) {
            console.log( req);
        },
        error:function (req, status, error) {
            console.log(req);
        }
    });
```

but result like this
[image]

How can i send data as;
 queryOptionsDTO: (binary)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the FileReader object to read a file's contents:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.addEventListener('load', function () {
   var result = fileReader.result;
   $hidden.val(result);
});
fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

The FileReader object reads the file async and triggers a callback on completion.  Using, this, you can then take the file's contents and send it to AJAX by posting the results from the file reader (base 64 string).

Adapted from my [original blog post](https://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2017/06/26/ajax-file-uploads-with-html-5/).

There are also other plugins like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/implementing-uploadify/) that can provide this functionality.

Comment: This is not for uploading, This is for sending data in binary format but i did not know how to use.

Comment: I'm saying you can read the file as base 64 string, and send data in string format instead...